# Is there a difference between new List<int>(array) and array.ToList()?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, generic-list

Is there a difference between getting an array into a List via  array.ToList() method and to do do it via new List(array) in the code below, in terms of its performance and its costs under the hood?

```
IEnumerable<int> array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
List<int> list_Foo = new List<int>(array);
List<int> list_Bar = array.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; the `Enumerable.ToList<T>` extension method is just a wrapper that calls the `List(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor.

The only additional costs you'll incur from `ToList` are an extra method call and nullity check, which are typically negligible (and might even be eliminated by the JIT compiler).

Answer (score 2):

Internally, here's what the call to `array.ToList()` (`Enumerable.ToList()`) looks like:

```
if (source == null)
    throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");

return new List<TSource>(source);
```

So your second example runs the same code as your first example.